# Accept only defined parameters for generated Spring-Server

Tags: spring, openapi, swagger-editor

First, I generated a spring-server using https://editor.swagger.io/.

The spring-server works quite well, but ignores these parameters that were not defined by me. So if I send a request to the server with the following JSON,

```
{  
"art": "PK",  
"termin": "2019-12-31",  
"betrag": 120000,  
"test": "test"  
}
```

then I want to get an error, because the parameter "test" is not defined in my swagger.

My swagger code looks like this:

```
openapi: 3.0.1  
info:  
...  
...  
paths:  
 /vorgang:  
  post:  
   tags:  
   - vorgang  
   summary: Adds a vorgang  
   description: Adds a vorgang  
   operationId: addVorgang  
   requestBody:  
    description: procedure object  
    content:  
     application/json:  
      schema:  
       $ref: '#/components/schemas/Vorgang'  
    required: true  
...  
...  
components:  
 schemas:  
  Vorgang:  
   type: object  
   properties:  
    art:  
     type: string  
     enum:  
     - PK  
     - FK  
    termin:  
     type: string  
     format: date  
    betrag:  
     type: number  
     format: double  
   required:  
   - art  
   - termin  
   - betrag
```

Comment: Can you add `additionalProperties: false` to your `Vorgang` schema, re-generate the server and see if this resolves the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not recognize a difference. Additional parameters are still ignored and the request is carried out.

Comment: Nobody who can't help me?